# HDD sometimes not recognised by BIOS during boot-up, not always

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata

I have recently built a new machine with Intel G2030 4GB RAM and Asus H61-M-K mobo. I am using a 160 GB HDD (Seagate) from an old Core2 Duo machine. In the old machine, the BIOS sometimes would not recognize the HDD. I would push the SATA cable to the connectors on both ends and then it would boot-up smooth. Please note the SATA cables were firmly connected (with clips). I always suspected this to be a mobo problem.

Now, however, the same problem is occurring again in the new machine even though the mobo and the SATA cable are both brand new. Without a doubt, this is a HDD problem.

My question is: *Do I have to replace the HDD or is there any way to fix the issue?*

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  Time to replace the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same cables it was using in the old machine, you could try to swap them. If that doesn't solve your problem, the you most likely have an issue with the connector on the drive. You could refurbish the drive yourself if you're handy, but I would probably just go out and buy a new one.